# Connection Error in Ignite web agent

Tags: gridgain, ignite

For analysis of node in Apache ignite, I am using monitoring tool at [1] : https://console.gridgain.com/. I tried running **ignite-web-agent.sh** for making connection with web server at link above, but I am getting following error messege. I also tried replacing localhost with IP address of machine, but still it is not working. While running ignite node do I have to start ignite REST server for connection? If yes then how can I enable this REST server mode through java code?

```
     ignite-web-agent-1.7.2]$ . ignite-web-agent.sh
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
 [12:58:13,881][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Starting Apache Ignite Web Console Agent...

 Agent configuration:
 User's security tokens        : ****************Fq3q
 URI to Ignite node REST server: http://localhost:8080
 URI to Ignite Console server  : https://console.gridgain.com:3002
 Path to agent property file   : default.properties
 Path to JDBC drivers folder   : /home/rishikesh/ignite-web-agent-1.7.2/jdbc-drivers

 [12:58:14,318][INFO ][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connecting to: https://console.gridgain.com:3002
 [12:58:34,314][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connection error.
 io.socket.client.SocketIOException: timeout
     at io.socket.client.Manager$1$4$1.run(Manager.java:312)
     at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12:58:37,304][INFO ][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connecting to: https://console.gridgain.com:3002
[12:58:53,744][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connection error.
io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onError(Transport.java:64)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR.access$100(PollingXHR.java:18)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$6$1.run(PollingXHR.java:126)
     at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: console.gridgain.com
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request$1.run(PollingXHR.java:214)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web agent can't resolve console.gridgain.com
try to change 'URI to Ignite Console server' in **/home/rishikesh/ignite-web-agent-1.7.2/default.properties** please replace:

```
server-uri=https://console.gridgain.com:3002
```

to:

```
server-uri=https://104.197.2.239:3002
```

To enable REST module move **ignite-rest-http** folder from lib/optional/ to lib/ in binary distribution or add following dependence to your maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-rest-http/artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried replacing server-uri with IP address as you mentioned above but still connection error is present. I also moved ignite-rest-http from lib/optional to lib/ folder and added External jar files from **ignite-rest-http** to my Java project for dependency. What might be problem?

Comment: Could you test that you not behind firewall or proxy? What `ping 104.197.2.239` shows?

Comment: I exported proxy settings for both http and https but still connection error is present. What might be issue?

Comment: If you connect through proxy, you should enable it for java app.
Please run agent with following options to use system proxy:
`JVM_OPTS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true" ./ignite-web-agent.sh`

Please run agent with following options to use custom proxy:
`JVM_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy-ip> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy-port>" ./ignite-web-agent.sh`